# How to add multiple files into a .gitignore file in the proper way?

Tags: linux, git, gitignore

Here, I'm using a linux terminal.
Assume, I have created a new directory

```
mkdir project_new
cd project_new
git init
```

And I've created two new files

```
touch a.txt b.txt
```

Now I'm staging and committing

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Add two new files a.txt b.txt'
```

Creating a .gitignore and made it as a hidden file

```
touch .gitignore
echo .DS_Store >.gitignore
```

Now can you help me out in the next steps

how to add both 'a.txt' & 'b.txt' inside the .gitignore to make them as untracked files?

Comment: Before answering your question let me clarify my doubt, do you want to ignore only thoes 2 text files or all text files?

Comment: only those two text files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already committed your files. They fall into the category of `tracked files` and are rightfully being tracked by git. You need to remove the files first from the index.

`git rm --cached <path-to-files>`

Since your a.txt and b.txt are sitting under the root of project, you just need to run,

`git rm --cached a.txt b.txt`

Add the files to `.gitignore` as follows,

```
/a.txt
/b.txt
```

Commit your changes and then going forward changes to a.txt and b.txt will be ignored by git.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your reference, I always add * into .gitignore to ignore everything, then while I need to add some thing, I use "git add -f". De facto, in most cases, too many temporary files are generated that do not need to be concerned; only in a few cases, some files need to be concerned and added.